# Angular 8 router outlet name can't working

Tags: angular-router, angular8

I have multiple router-outlet so with an induvial name but it raises some error like  Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tournament'

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { TournamentsComponent } from  './tournaments/tournaments.component'
import { TournamentsListComponent } from './tournaments/tournaments-list/tournaments-list.component';
import { AuthenticationComponent } from './authentication/authentication.component';
import { AuthenticationModule } from './authentication/authentication.module';

const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path:'',pathMatch:'full',redirectTo:'login'
  },
    {
      path:'tournament',component:TournamentsComponent,pathMatch:'full',outlet:'secondDate'
    },
    {
      path:'home',component:NavbarComponent
    }
  ];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponent =[TournamentsComponent,NavbarComponent, TournamentsListComponent ]
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule,routingComponent } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthenticationComponent } from './authentication/authentication.component';
import { AuthenticationModule} from './authentication/authentication.module';
import { ServicesComponent } from './services/services.component';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
// import { TournamentsModule } from './tournaments/tournaments.module';
// import { NavbarModule } from './navbar/navbar.module';
// import { DataRoutingModule } from './data-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    routingComponent
  ],
  imports: [

    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule, 
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AuthenticationModule,
    // TournamentsModule,
    // NavbarModule
    // DataRoutingModule,

  ],providers: [ CookieService ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

navbar.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NavbarComponent } from  './navbar.component';
import { AppRoutingModule,routingComponent } from '../app-routing.module'
// import { TournamentsModule } from '../tournaments/tournaments.module';
import { TournamentsComponent } from '../tournaments/tournaments.component';

// const routes: Routes = [
//     {
//       path:'tournament',component:TournamentsComponent, outlet:'tour'
//     }
//   ];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [NavbarComponent,routingComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    // TournamentsModule,
    RouterModule,
    // RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
    // RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class NavbarModule { }
```

navbar.component.ts

```
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">
        <div class="body-wrap">
                <div class="container">
                  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-light bg-light"  role="navigation">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SRFI</a>
                      </div>

                      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                          <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SRFI <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                  <li><a href="#">Office Bearers</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Committee</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">State Units</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Associate Members</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                          <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Events <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <!-- <li><a [routerLink]='[{ outlets: { tourn: ["/tournament"] } }]' routerLinkActive="active">Calendar</a></li> -->
                              <li><a routerLink='/tournament' routerLinkActive="active">Cendar</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Regulations</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Conduct an Event</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Event Funding</a></li>
                              <!-- <li class="divider"></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                              <li class="divider"></li>
                              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li> -->
                            </ul>
                          </li>    
                          <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ISPIN <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">A to Z</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Rankings</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Core Players</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Refrees</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Coaches</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">IndianSquashTV</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
                  </nav>
                </div>
                <router-outlet name='secondDate'></router-outlet>
              </div>             

</body>
```

tournaments.component.html

```
<!-- <app-navbar></app-navbar> -->
<div class='layout'>
    <!-- <app-tournaments-list *ngFor="let tour of tournament" [tour]="tour"></app-tournaments-list> -->
    <div>
        <div class="container">
                <hr class="mt-2 mb-5">

                <div class="row text-center text-lg-left">

                  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">

                        <h3>Id :{{tournament.TournamentID}}</h3>
                        <h3>Tournament Name : {{tournament.tournament_name}}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- <div *ngFor="let tour of tournament">
        {{tour.TournamentID}}
        {{tour.venue}}
    </div> -->
</div>
```

when  I click events -> 'Cender' it raises
'
 Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tournament'
'